# Are Quartz event services/event taps deprecated?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, accessibility

Event taps provide a way to create assistive technologies as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_event_services):

> Event taps are designed to serve as a Section 508 enabling technology.

The same link also says:

> These functions are still supported, but they are not recommended for
>   new development.

So is there a newer API that is recommended now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read

> Quartz Event Services also includes an older set of event-related functions declared in the file CGRemoteOperation.h. These functions are still supported, but they are not recommended for new development.

Don't use the functions in CGRemoteOperation.h for new development. The functions in the linked documentation are in CGEvent.h (I didn't check them all) and can be used.

Comment: oh damn, I guess I missed that while skimming. am accepting your answer, but how did you know about CGEvent.h? (am new to macOS development), and is there anywhere I can get better documentation about these events that the linked resource?

Comment: I have a Search Scope "FrameWork Headers" in Xcode and searched for one of the functions. Another way to find the header: paste the function in source code and Command-Click on the function name. Sometimes the comments in the header are more usefull than the documentation.